# Evaluate $I = \iint_{R}\frac{x}{y^{4}}\,dx\,dy$ over a given region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

> Evaluate the double integral $$I = \iint_{R}\frac{x}{y^{4}}\,dx\,dy$$ over the region $R = \{(x,y)\mid 0\le x \le3, 3\le y \le5\}$.

Hi I was wondering if anyone could help me on this question which involves Taylor's Expansion.

This is what I have done so far:

From using the given boundaries I have created the integral:

$$\int_3^5\int_0^3 \frac{x}{y^4}\, dx\,dy$$

Then I worked out the first integral:

$$\int_0^3\frac{x}{y^4}\, dx$$

which gives me $\frac{9}{2y^4}$ and then I put this into the next integral that is with respect to $y$:

$$\int_3^5\frac{9}{2y^4} \,dy$$

Which gives me $3.415703704\times 10^{-3}$, which is evidently wrong as the correct answer is: $49/1125$

Can someone please help me on where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This does not involve Taylor's expansion. Everything you wrote is correct up to "$\displaystyle\int_3^5 \frac9{2y^4}dy$".

Comment: Apologies, I meant double integrals and got muddled up. Can you advise me on where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Exactly *how* did you calculate the integral I mentioned above? The value you obtained is wrong; everything is correct except that step.

Comment: Unfortunately I have made a silly mistake in the calculation of the integral and have treated the denominator as a numerator and added 1 to the power 4 instead of (-4).

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
& \int_3^5 \left( \int_0^3 \frac{x}{y^4}\, dx \right) \,dy \\ {} \\
= {} & \int_3^5 \left( \frac 1 {y^4} \int_0^3 x\,dx \right) \, dy \\
& \text{because $1/y^4$ remains} \\
& \text{constant as $x$ goes from $0$ to $3$} \\ {} \\
= {} & \int_3^5 \frac 1 {y^4} \, dy \cdot \int_0^3 x\, dx \\
& \text{because the integral with respect to $x$} \\
& \text{remains constant as $y$ goes from $3$ to $5$}
\end{align}
$$
So in this case you just have two integrals each with respect to one variable. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:

$$\int\int_{R}\frac{x}{y^{4}}\ dx\ dy = \int_{3}^{5}\int_{0}^{3}\frac{x}{y^{4}}\ dx\ dy = \int_{3}^{5}\bigg(\frac{x^{2}}{2y^{4}}\bigg)\bigg\vert_{0}^{3}\ dy = \int_{3}^{5}\frac{9}{2y^{4}}\ dy$$

$$= -\frac{3}{2y^{3}}\bigg\vert_{3}^{5} = -\frac{3}{250} + \frac{1}{18} = \boxed{\frac{49}{1125}}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
Every well-bred young people should know the formula
$$\int\frac{\mathrm d t}{t^n}=-\frac 1{(n-1)t^{n-1}} \qquad ({}+C)$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I'm not quite sure why you have put 'Every well-bred young people' though as clearly I have just made a mistake and I am trying to learn from this.

Comment: @TaylorS. I'm almost sure Bernard only tried to joke a little and didn't try to be offensive at all. That formula he mentions is, in fact, pretty important...and it is true for any $\;n\in\Bbb R\setminus\{1\}\;$

Comment: @TaylorS. It was not a joke specifically against you. Many students don't know it and try to find the answer with negative exponents, which is also a correct method, but very error prone whereas knowing this formula (which is quite easy to remember: the antiderivative of $\tfrac1{x^3}$ is $-\frac1{2x^2}$, of $\tfrac1{x^4}$,   $-\frac1{3x^3}$, &c.) is much more safe. Unfortunately many teachers do not teach it.

Comment: @DonAntonio: You can be quite sure. Sometimes, when an induction proof a particularly easy,  I also speak of a ‘nursery induction’. I do hope no one takes it in bad part.